# How to enter into the BIOS setup of a MSI P55-GD65 motherboard

Tags: bios

When I'm restarting my PC I have no instructions on how to get to BIOS. I mean no key combination for that or something. At all. I restarted my PC many times and wasn't able to see something about that.

I tried basically all the Fn (F2,F11, F12, F3, F1 etc.) keys. I also tried Del, Esc and even more. Don't even remember all this keys and combinations I've tried while trying get into BIOS.

My Motherboard is MSI  P55-GD65 I've read the manual for this keyboard which suggested using the F11 key. But as I've alredy said it doesn't work for me. All it does is restart my computer.

How can I get into BIOS?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1075341/cant-get-to-bios-on-an-msi-motherboard

Comment: https://www.technewstoday.com/msi-motherboard-bios-key/

Comment: Have running. Restart.  Any screen that says Enter to get into BIOS?

Comment: The [manual](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/P55GD65/support#manual) that I've downloaded clearly says it's the **DELETE** key.

«Power on the computer and the system will start POST (Power On Self Test) process. When the message below appears on the screen, press **<DEL>** key to enter Setup.

_Press DEL to enter SETUP_

If the message disappears before you respond and you still wish to enter Setup, restart the system by turning it OFF and On or pressing the RESET button. You may also restart the system by simultaneously pressing **<Ctrl>**, **<Alt>**, and **<Delete>** keys.»

Comment: Is the keyboard connected to the PS/2 keyboard port or to an USB port?

Comment: how can `the manual for this keyboard` suggest which key to press to get into BIOS??

Comment: Which operating system? Windows and Linux have command line methods to get into BIOS (though, I think that may be UEFI motherboards, not BIOS ones)

Comment: TL;DR - disconnect every USB device except your keyboard - details: I once had a mouse that prevented getting into UEFI whenever it was just plugged in! No idea what was going on, but none of the methods I know of getting into UEFI would work while that mouse was plugged in. Once I disconnected the mouse and got in to do a BIOS upgrade, the problem disappeared!! So I can only conclude that the mouse was somehow "incompatible" with the BIOS (I don't like that explanation either)