Cannot access bios nor any boot or OS - BOOTMGR is compressed
Whenever I start my computer, I see the MSI logo without the usual shortcuts to access the Boot menu, BIOS, or Setup. Then I get the following message:
BOOTMGR is compressed
Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart

When I proceed as instructed, the result is always the same: the MSI logo and the message above.
I tried pressing all the possible keys when the MSI logo appears. I tried holding down Del, Esc, F2, F10, F11 and F12 (1 attempt for each key) before turning on power. I also tried removing the battery and pressing the power button for 30 seconds to drain any stored charge in the system. Nothing changed.
I can't access BIOS and I can't access any boot menu to start on an external usb key.
How can I solve this?

Have you tried holding down the appropriate key to access BIOS,  (e.g., Del or F2) before turning on power, and keeping it held until BIOS shows? See also https://superuser.com/questions/1075341/cant-get-to-bios-on-an-msi-motherboard about keyboard causing issue.

I just tried holding down Del, Esc, F2, F10, F11 and F12 (1 attempt for each key) before turning on power but it didn't work.
